# Showing div's based on number chosen with radio button

Tags: jquery

I have 4 div's that need to be shown commensurate with the number next to the radio button selected. So if I click on 1 then only div #1 shows. If I select 3 then div's 1 thru 3 show. I've seen solutions on this site where it either shows or hides a div or element. I haven't found anything that allows you to pick a number from say an "id" and then show that number of divs.

My HTML is simple enough:

```
<input type="radio" name="sNum" value="1"><span>1</span>
<input type="radio" name="sNum" value="2"><span>2</span>
<input type="radio" name="sNum" value="3"><span>3</span>
<input type="radio" name="sNum" value="4"><span>4</span>
<br />
<div id="g1" class="gSet">
  content here
</div>
<div id="g2" class="gSet">
  content here
</div>
<div id="g3" class="gSet">
  content here
</div>
<div id="g4" class="gSet">
  content here
</div>
```

I'm just not sure how to go about doing this and welcome any suggestions versus me doing a kludge based on what I know. I know I need to take the value of the input selected and match it up with the corresponding ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('div.gSet').hide();
    $("div.gSet:lt("+val+")").show();
});
```

Working Demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/uS7SA/1/

Comment: Why are you selecting the `.gSet` elements twice? - `$(".gSet").hide().filter(":lt(" + this.value + ")").show();`

Comment: @Andreas - your solution works well. I just need to make sure that all the divs are hidden initially.

Comment: @Andreas - I figured it out. I forgot to put display:none in my css. I'm good now. Thank you for your help. I learned a lot. More reading to be done it would seem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was way off-base with the way I was trying it. I learned a lot. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio').on('change',function(){
    $('#g'+$(this).val()).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle For you..](http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/HNrFn/1/)